# Handling division by 0 error and nan issue in python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to calculate average contrast of an image using this code:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

pip install mahotas

import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
import mahotas
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.transform import resize
import pandas as pd
from numpy import *


data_path = "/content/drive/My 
Drive/ADIP/seperate_ricepests5/seperate_ricepests5/"
x_image = []
y_label = []
image_dataset = pd.DataFrame()

labels = os.listdir(data_path)
for dirname in labels:
    filepath = os.path.join(data_path, dirname)
    print("Extracting ",dirname," ... ")
    for file in os.listdir(filepath):

        filename = os.path.join(filepath, file)       
        image = cv2.imread(filename)
        image_resized = cv2.resize(image, (300,300))
        image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image_resized, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)     

        df = pd.DataFrame()

        lab = cv2.cvtColor(image_resized,cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
        L,A,B=cv2.split(lab)
        # compute minimum and maximum in 5x5 region using erode and 
        dilate
        kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
        min = cv2.erode(L,kernel,iterations = 1)
        max = cv2.dilate(L,kernel,iterations = 1)
        # convert min and max to floats
        min = min.astype(np.float64) 
        max = max.astype(np.float64) 
        # compute local contrast
        #contrast = (max-min)/(max+min)
        try:
          contrast = (max-min)/(max+min)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
          contrast = 0

        #print(contrast)
    
        average_contrast = 100*np.mean(contrast)
        print(average_contrast)
    
        #average_contrast = 0 if isnan(contrast.all) else 
        100*np.mean(contrast)
        df['Average_Contrast'] = str(average_contrast)

        image_dataset = image_dataset.append(df)
```

Issue-1: when it compute local contrast on line (1) it get division by 0 and gives error.
Issue-2: i don't want to see nan, i want to see 0 instead of nan.

I've tried a lot but couldn't find any solution.

Error(by using set of images pass to this code)

```
12.399144455618014
8.153193046496428
21.500097694214016
6.484668625777974
4.184483018281615
7.769430843626425
6.542391950067563
8.547638297275716
9.426613716832737
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:147: RuntimeWarning: invalid 
value encountered in true_divide
nan
6.25553159262818
10.847396421660804
nan
```

Comment: Have you try [error handling with try.. expect](https://docs.python.org/fr/3.5/tutorial/errors.html) ?

Comment: I suggest that you refer to the documentation for cvtColor. Also, as an aside, why are you overriding the Python built-in functions min & max?

Comment: Check for your denominator == 0 before dividing; e.g. `contrast = (max-min)/(max+min) if (max+min) else 0`  Though the numerator is zero in your case too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to raise an exception in case of specific error.

```
a = 5
b = 0

try:
    print(a/b)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("You can't divide by zero!")
```

I think in your case it would look like this

```
max = 10
min = -10

try:
    contrast = (max - min) / (max + min)
    print(contrast)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    contrast = 0
    print('You tried to divide by zero!')
```

Comment: let me try that...How about nan values how can i transform them into 0

Comment: After that exception your `contrast` will be 0 becasue you set it as 0 in this exception. After multiplying `np.mean(contrast)` by 100 it will still be 0 so the print should change from nan to 0

Comment: Still same error... may be average_contrast line is giving me this error.. can i put this line in try except block as well

Comment: @Qasim0787So the error doesn't occur on line 1 as you stated in your original question. How about showing some reproducible code?

Comment: @Qasim0787 If it doesnt work that means the error is not in the line where you divide. Can you show in what line exactly the error occurs?

Comment: The program does not work. Problem is in the path `/content/drive/MyDrive/ADIP/seperate_ricepests5/seperate_ricepests5/` I suppose this is the path to the stuff at google drive. But I think the program searches this path in my system. This line is the problem `labels = os.listdir(data_path)`

Answer (score 2):

If your problem is in the fact that division by zero occurs, you could try to change this:

```py
contrast = (max-min)/(max+min)
```

to this:

```py
epsilon = 2.22e-308
contrast = (max - min)/(max + min + epsilon)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use the built-in `max` and `min` as variable names.

Assuming the variables are called `a` and `b`, you can use `np.where`:

```
np.random.seed(0)
a = np.random.rand(5,5).astype(np.float64)
b = np.random.rand(5,5).astype(np.float64)

#Set zeros to force division by 0
a[1][1] = 0
b[1][1] = 0

>>> np.where(b+a==0, 0, b-a/b+a)
array([[  0.33110759,  -4.13045606,   0.9093639 ,   0.02259059, -0.18337047],
       [ -1.53098067,   0.64663339,  -0.6070747 ,  -0.16319746, -20.0046655],
       [  0.127496  ,   0.27691841,   0.26422437,   0.88857807,  0.64867046],
       [  0.20428008,   0.41098738,   0.33675532, -12.08234268,  0.23195646],
       [  0.19002108,  -2.78905587,  -2.98899878,  -1.37854793,  0.15679707] 
      ])
```